# Остановить выполнение скрипта php из ajax по условию

Tags: php, laravel

Есть скрипт который может выполняться больше часа. Скрипт запускается по ajax по кнопке старт. Как можно послать сигнал скрипту, чтобы он остановился?

По окончанию работы скрипт должен сделать статистику сколько работал.

Есть идея создать файл при запуске. И проверять на его наличие. Если он есть, то продолжать работать. А есть ли лучше способ?

```
if(isset($_GET['stop'])){
    unlink('check_file');
    return 'deleting!!!!';
}
if(!file_exists('check_file')){
    fopen('check_file','w');
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if(file_exists('check_file')){ //Есть другие варианты?
        //времязатратная задача
        info('working...');
        sleep(1);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
info('job stopped. was working: ' . $i . ' seconds');
```

Проект не позволяет использовать редисы или вебсокеты.

Comment: Врядли такое возможно в php, смотри в сторону nodejs

Comment: чушь собачья, возможно все. или файл создавай или в бд статус пиши

Answer (score 0):

Попробую подсказать алгоритм. Создай второй роут, который будет принимать запрос на остановку выполнения. В этом втором роуте создаёшь некий флаг (файл? redis? бд?), а в твоём долгоиграющем цикле проверяешь выставлен ли флаг. Если выставлен, `break`. И просто в нужный момент делаешь запрос по второму роуту, флаг проставляется, в долгоиграющем цикле срабатывает `break`.

P.S. Не исключаю, что сейчас кто-то вспомнит о веб-сокетах, но если автору вопроса этот путь в голову не пришёл, значит, на текущий момент это не наш метод.